# is possible to combine where clause when whereAutogenerate is used?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I will like to combine these to where clause together.   I got the error 
LinqDataSource does not support the Where property when AutoGenerateWhereClause is true.

The first where clause is coming from the apointement table.  I want to select only the rows with the column IsAvailable = True.

The other where is coming from a dropdownlist.  I will like to know how to combine but if it is feasible.   Thanks

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"
      ContextTypeName="DoctorDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
      EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Apointement" 
      AutoGenerateWhereClause="True"
      Where="@IsAvailable = True"> 

      <WhereParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter 
             Name="doctorName" 
             ControlID="DropDownList1" 
             PropertyName="SelectedValue"
             Type="String" />
      </WhereParameters>

 </asp:LinqDataSource>

 <div class="center">

 <asp:Label ID="lbldoctorName" runat="server" Text="Choose a doctor">   
 </asp:Label>

 <div class="value-right"> 
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="180px" AutoPostBack="true" 
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
           <asp:ListItem Text="doctorA" Value="doctorA" />
           <asp:ListItem Text="doctorB" Value="doctorB" />
           <asp:ListItem Text="doctorC" Value="doctorC" />

     </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `<asp:ControlParameter` to the `<WhereParameters>` element. I'm not up-to-date on LinqDataSources so I don't know the syntax, but you'd specify the IsAvailable column with a value of True, or maybe 1.

Comment: what I did is to remove the AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" and it works the only problem is the first time all choices from the dropdownlist show up.  The field IsAvailable comes from a table so how to you want I do this in the <asp:ControlParameter ?

Answer (score 0):

what I did is to remove the AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" and it works the only problem is the first time all choices from the dropdownlist show up.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"
  ContextTypeName="DoctorDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
  EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Apointement" 
  Where="@IsAvailable = True"> 
  <WhereParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter 
         Name="doctorName" 
         ControlID="DropDownList1" 
         PropertyName="SelectedValue"
         Type="String" />
  </WhereParameters>

</asp:LinqDataSource>
```